# How to capture inner matched value in indexWhere vector expression?

Tags: scala, vector

Using a Vector[Vector[Int]] reference v, and the expression to find a given number num:

```
val posX = v.indexWhere(_.indexOf(num) > -1)
```

Is there any way to capture the value of _.indexOf(num) to use after the expression (i.e. the posY value)? The following signals an error 'Illegal start of simple expression':

```
val posX = v.indexWhere((val posY = _.indexOf(num)) > -1)
```

Comment: Hello from the Functional programming course in Scala! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are lots of nice functional ways to do this. The following is probably one of the more concise:

```
val v = Vector(Vector(1, 2, 3), Vector(4, 5, 6), Vector(7, 8, 9))
val num = 4

val Some((posY, posX)) = v.map(_ indexOf num).zipWithIndex.find(_._1 > -1)
// posY: Int = 0
// posX: Int = 1
```

Note that there's a lot of extra work going on here, though—we're creating a couple of intermediate collections, parts of which we don't need, etc. If you're calling this thing a lot or on very large collections, you unfortunately may need to take a more imperative approach. In that case I'd suggest bundling up all the unpleasantness:

```
def locationOf(v: Vector[Vector[Int]])(num: Int): Option[(Int, Int)] = {
  var i, j = 0
  var found = false

  while (i < v.size && !found) {
    j = 0

    while (j < v(i).size && !found)
      if (v(i)(j) == num) found = true else j += 1

    if (!found) i += 1
  }

  if (!found) None else Some(i, j)
}
```

Not as elegant, but this method is probably going to be a lot faster and more memory efficient. It's small enough that it isn't likely to contain any of the bugs that this kind of programming is so prone to, and it's referentially transparent—all the mutation is local.

Answer (score 7):

If we do not mind using a variable then we can capture `indexOf()` value of inner Vector (`_` in the below code) in a var and use it later to build the y position:

```
val posX = v.indexWhere(_.indexOf(num) > -1)
val posY = v(posX).indexOf(num)
```

Answer (score 2):

From my armchair,

```
scala> val v = Vector(Vector(1, 2, 3), Vector(4, 5, 6), Vector(7, 8, 9))

scala> v.zipWithIndex collectFirst {
     | case (e, i) if (e indexOf num) >= 0 =>
     |   (i, e indexOf num)
     | }
res7: Option[(Int, Int)] = Some((1,0))
```

I haven't done the armchair math, but that's one intermediate collection compared to Travis's.  But see Travis's comment that the result inner index is computed twice here, and the whole point was not to do that.

Comment: You could add `.view` before `.zipWithIndex` to get 0 intermediate collections.

Comment: Note that this saves an intermediate collection by searching each inner vector twice (`e indexOf num`).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that will only evaluate up until it finds the required element. I personally find it more readable and you can reuse it across programs. You can obviously make this more general if need be.

```
val v = Vector(Vector(1, 2, 3), Vector(4, 5, 6))

def findElem(i: Int, vs: Vector[Vector[Int]]): (Int, Int) =
    (for {
      row <- vs.indices.toStream
      col <- vs(row).indices.toStream
      if vs(row)(col) == i
    }  yield (row, col)).head

findElem(5, v) // (1, 1)
```

You could remove the `.toStream` methods if you want all positions. Using the `.toStream` just means that you will only evaluate up until the first occurrence.